# Replace a String in Custom Connect To Statement in qlikview

Tags: qlikview

I am using a REST Connector in Qlikview and i need to pass a variable to the CUSTOM CONNECT TO Statement when connecting to a Web Service.

```
CUSTOM CONNECT TO "Provider=QVRestConnector.exe;url="http://test.example.com?auth=2334342assa13"
```

Now, instead of the auth token directly getting passed, i need to provide it at the RunTime. I tried the below but its not working.

```
Let vToken="a3122423421f";
"Provider=QVRestConnector.exe;url="http://test.example.com?auth=$(vToken)"
```

Comment: I'm not sure of it but what if you nested the variables another level. so; let vConnect = 'Provider=QVRestConnector.exe;url="http://test.example.com?auth=$(vToken)"'; and then CONNECT TO $(vConnect)? I'm in no way sure of this just something I would try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to replace

```
Let vToken="a3122423421f";
```

With

```
Let vToken='a3122423421f';
```

A string in QlikView is defined with the ' character, " represents for instance field names.